# What is software-properties-common

Tags: software-installation

I have been installing a couple of softwares and I noticed that when you are to install a software from a PPA, the command is usually preceeded with

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

I look for why installing this package but I could not get a reason.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As described in `apt show software-properties-common`

> This software provides an abstraction of the used apt repositories.
> It  allows you to easily manage your distribution and independent
> software  vendor software sources.

In practice that means it provides some useful scripts for adding and removing PPAs:

```
$ dpkg -L software-properties-common | grep 'bin/'
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository
/usr/bin/apt-add-repository
```

plus the DBUS backends to do the same via the Software and Updates GUI.

Without it, you would need to add and remove repositories (such as PPAs) manually by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and/or any subsidiary files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: how to launch this via graphical interface from terminal?

Comment: Linux packages names always reflect so intuitively their purpose. The package abstracts APT repositories and it does not even have "repository" in its name.

Comment: `apt-show packagename` appears to be `apt show packagename` (no hyphen) for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

Comment: @steeldriver I just tried to install `apt-show`, please fix this (to `apt show`) as I am not allowed to change just one character.

Comment: @user2121 done - thanks for bringing this to my attention